# Can I pass a matrix as command line input in python with numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, command-line-arguments

I'm working on a simple program that gives me the next step of Conway's game of life, using numpy. 
Right now, all I can do is alter the ones and zeros in the program :-

```
seed = np.array([[0,0,0,0],[0,1,1,0],[0,1,1,1],[0,0,0,0]])  
print(nextStep(seed))
```

But I'd like to be able to pass the initial array in command line. Any way I can do this ?

Answer (score 5):

What you want is basically to convert text into structured data (numpy array here). Because doing so manually (like splitting strings or using `eval`) is fraught with bugs and security vulnerabilities, I recommend using a library that does the parsing for you.

Here I think `json` is the most natural format. Example usage

```
import json
import numpy
import sys

data = numpy.array(json.loads(sys.argv[1]))
# do you calculation
```

Now you can run on the command line

```
python myscript.py '[[0,0,0,0],[0,1,1,0],[0,1,1,1],[0,0,0,0]]'
```

Answer (score 1):

eval can do that :

```
python myprogram.py "[[0,0,0,0],[0,1,1,0],[0,1,1,1],[0,0,0,0]]"
```

python code :

```
import sys

...
...

seed = np.array(eval(sys.argv[1]))
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm able to enter the arrays in command line this way but the output now is exactly what I'm passing as the input !

Comment: https://ideone.com/625Pr5 Show you that after calling "eval" the string passed as the input is now the list. Exactly that you pass to np.array function.

Comment: I would recommend against running `eval` on plain `sys.argv` data for security reasons.

Comment: Sure, datas would have to be checked before running eval, but it's not the subject of this thread

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write

```
$ python life.py 0101010,0101010,0101010
```

then you need the `argv` vector from the `sys` module, that contains all the elements in the command line, and then a simple list comprehension
to split the 1st argument on commas, hence `r`ows of your matrix (note that these rows are strings) and then build a sub-list converting each character in a row

```
from sys import argv
...
life = np.array([[int(c) for c in r] for r in argv[1].split(',')])
```

To show in detail the procedure, using an auxiliary variable in place of `argv[1]`

```
In [46]: m = '0101010,0101010,0101010'

In [47]: [r for r in m.split(',')]
Out[47]: ['0101010', '0101010', '0101010']

In [48]: [[c for c in r] for r in m.split(',')]
Out[48]: 
[['0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0'],
 ['0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0'],
 ['0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0']]

In [49]: [[int(c) for c in r] for r in m.split(',')]
Out[49]: [[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]]

In [50]: np.array([[int(c) for c in r] for r in m.split(',')])
Out[50]: 
array([[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]])

In [51]:
```