# Passing numpy array as parameter in command line

Tags: python

I am building several histograms, and I want to pass the bins parameter in command line. However, the bins may be unequally spaced sometimes, so I would prefer to pass the numpy function directly to command like, this:

`python test.py arr=np.arange(0,10,2)`

Or some other numpy array or matrix. My code can read what happens after the `=` sign, so in this case I have something like

`kwargs['arr'] = 'np.arange(0,10,2)'`

so that it is read as a string. I've checked [Can I pass a matrix as command line input in python with numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28851053/can-i-pass-a-matrix-as-command-line-input-in-python-with-numpy) but assumes that everything is an `np.array`; what I want here is that it could be `np.arange`, or just `range`, or even `np.array`. So I'd prefer to make that string run as it is, if possible. I'd like to **avoid** something like

```
if 'np.arange' in kwargs['arr']:
    # some string manipulations here
    arr = np.arange(effective_str)
elif 'range' in kwargs['arr']:
    # and so on
```

Is there such a way?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out. `eval` does the trick.

`eval('np.arange(0,10,2)') = array([0,2,4,6,8])`

I've heard there are some bugs with `eval` though, so if there's any problem with this, please let me know.

EDIT:

In command line, you have to put `np.arange(...)` in quotes:

`python test.py arr='np.arange(0,10,2)'`

Otherwise you get an error.

Comment: `eval` itself isn't buggy, but it can introduce a huge security risk into your code. If you aren't worried about this code being exposed to malicious inputs, go ahead and use it. This is pretty hacky though.

Comment: Ah I see. So other than eval...no other (easy, bug-free) way?

Comment: Not if you don't want to do some form of parsing of the inputs.